# Jquery UI Calendar - how to highlight days after the current date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a site for a client, on the site I use the [Jquery UI Calendar](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), I need to be able to highlight 3 business days starting 2 days after the current date but incorporate math to not count the weekends. Here is my fiddle:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw5fZ/4/)

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" id='datepicker'>
```

Here is the JS

```
var SelectedDates = {};
SelectedDates[new Date('04/14/2014')] = new Date('04/14/2014');
SelectedDates[new Date('04/15/2014')] = new Date('04/15/2014');
SelectedDates[new Date('04/16/2014')] = new Date('04/16/2014');

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: 2,
    maxDate: "+4M +15D",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        if (Highlight) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
        } else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});
```

I am having trouble adding `beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends` to the code above. I also need the 3 dates that are highlighted to be variable so they change depending on what the current date is but I am still learning JS and I don't understand the logic behind that.

I have looked all over this site and others and although there are a lot of questions/answers on how to highlight specific dates, none fully apply to what I am trying to do.

So just to clarify I need to do math to figure out how to negate the minDate and weekends and highlight the next three business days.

Comment: Why is minDate set to 2? That prevents someone from selecting tomorrow.

Comment: Because the date they are selecting is a ship date, and the minDate: 2 is basically the handling time

Comment: So would you want to highlight Friday, Monday, and Tuesday (today is Thursday), or Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday as your fiddle does? Your question says "3 business days after the current date" but that doesn't match the fiddle example.

Comment: I understand I did word it a little weird. Since today is Thursday I want it to highlight Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday. I tried to explain it a little better when I said "negate the minDate and weekends" but I see how it's still confusing, sorry about that.

Comment: but when it's Monday I need it to highlight Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday. And just keep going as the day changes.

Comment: So would that mean that you want to highlight the next three business days, starting two days from the current date?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, but it needs to not count the weekends. So if it was Wednesday then Friday, Monday, and Tuesday should be highlighted.

Comment: Can you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mw5fZ/5/ and tell me if this is close to what you want?

Comment: It appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. So when it is Wednesday will it highlight Friday, Monday, and Tuesday? also the highlight seems to disappear when a date is selected, is there a way to make them stay highlighted?

Comment: How's this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mw5fZ/6/? And you can test it out with other dates by changing the line `today = new Date();`. For example, April 20 would be `today = new Date(2014,3,20);` (the months are zero based). Let me know if this is what you need and if so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: This works exactly how I need it to work. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mw5fZ/6/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var css, count = 0,
        gap = 0,
        today = new Date();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: "+4M +15D",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            var diff = new Date(date - today);
            var numDays = Math.ceil(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
            if (numDays > 0 && count < 3) {
                if (day != 6 && day != 0) {
                    gap++;
                    if (gap > 1) {
                        count++;
                        css = 'Highlighted';
                    } else css = '';
                }
            } else css = '';
            return [(day != 6) && (day != 0), css]; //0-Sunday 6-Saturday
        },
        onSelect: function () {
            count = 0;
            gap = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Here is one way to do it:

```
var currentDay = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek;
    var highlighted = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var SelectedDates = {};

    while(highlighted < 3){
       dayOfWeek = currentDay.getDay();
        if(dayOfWeek != 0 && dayOfWeek != 6){
            if(count > 1){
                alert(currentDay);
                var month = currentDay.getMonth()+1;
                if(month.toString().length < 2)
                    month = '0'+month;
                var day = currentDay.getDate();
                if(day.toString().length < 2)
                    day = '0'+day;
                var year = currentDay.getFullYear();
                var dateStr = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;   
                SelectedDates[new Date(dateStr)] = new Date(dateStr);
                highlighted++;
            }
            else {
                count++;    
            }
        }
        currentDay = new Date(currentDay.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));    
    }
```

Example:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/XYY67/1/)

Comment: I just realized you probably want to count today as a business day as well if it is not a weekend.  I'll update my post.

Comment: @MatthewSechrest check my update.  It will work for you regardless of what day it is.

Comment: Ok this is working great! So with this if the current day is wednesday will the highlighted days be Friday, Monday, and Tuesday?

Comment: @MatthewSechrest Yes it would,  Take a look at this simulated example http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/XYY67/2/ , note however that your line of code minDate:2 is commented out.  UnComment that line and see what happens.

Comment: Anyway when you uncomment that line friday is grayed out but that is only because today is really thursday.  But if it was actually wednesday then it would not be grayed out. So no worries there.

Comment: Yes I did notice that, this works great and is another great solution, because @j08691 was the first I am marking his answer as correct.

Comment: BUT @Trevor you also deserve credit because your answer also works great. Upvote for you :)

Comment: Your Welcome @MatthewSechrest, and yes j08691 was very helpful to you.  I just noticed that the highlight does not stay on the calendar after the first time you pull it up.  But I'm glad you got a solution that works for you.